# Angular: How to bind varying inputs to parts of a string

Tags: angularjs

I have an ACTIONS list with 0..n number of parameters marked `~string~`.

Once an action is chosen a bound repeat iterates through the parameters and displays the corresponding input boxes if any.

for example:

```html
<tr>
   <td>{{action.description}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="pair in action.dataPairs track by $index" ng-model="action.dataPairs">
  <td>{{pair.name}}</td>
  <td>{{pair.dataType}}
    <input type="text" ng-disabled="pair.isOutput" ng-model="pair.value">
  </td>
</tr>
```

So when the description is `Search for a ~aString~` there will be one input below.

When `Compare ~string1~ to ~string2~` there will be two input boxes and so on.

My question is how do i bind the input box to the description so when the user writes in the input box the description is dynamically changed?

I've split description into an array to separate bindings but have no idea how to bind the parameter to it.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

There's a list of actions in a select box
When one is chosen it's description may contain parameters marked with a tilde.

Once an action is selected inputs are displayed if the action has parameters and I want those input boxes to bind to the description like:

`Compare ~string1~ to ~string2~`
`input 1 text` iPhone5
`input 2 text` iPhone6

Will be `Compare ~iPhone5~ to ~iPhone6~`

Comment: I have read the question twice, and I honestly can't understand what you're asking. Take a step back, and explain what you're trying to achieve, at a higher level. Post the relevant JavaScript code.

Comment: what does `split into array` mean?  This string comparison concept is really unclear

Comment: Ok thanks guys bare with me:

Comment: I've edited my question hopeful it's more clear, my code is huge i'll try and demo up an example

Comment: So, you want to replace the substring ~string1~ by ~iPhone5~? Is that the question? If so, read https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/replace.

Comment: @JBNizet, Thanks i'm aware of .replace. The question is what if the string is dynamic and may contain 0 to n number if ~string~ variables

Comment: Then, bind the inputs to two variables `a` and `b`, and use `replace()` to create "Compare ~iPhone5~ to ~iPhone6~" from "Compare ~string1~ to ~string2~" by replacing "~string1~" by the value of `a`, and `~string2~` by the value of `b`.

Comment: You also need to parse the string (using a regexp, for example, or using indexOf('~')), to extract all the parameters from the original string. Your question is too broad. What is the **specific** problem. You must manage to split you whole problems into separate parts: parse the string, create a form, replace the bound values, etc.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes that's what i did, But when i bind ng-if="desc.includes('~')" ng-bind="desc" it stays "desc" when it suppose to be "~string~"

Comment: Seems like it would be a lot simpler using extra properties in the objects for the `<select>`. Something like `isSplitDescription:true`. If you want more help you would be  best to create a simple demo that outlines this problem better

Comment: Not sure why you would like to solve it in the template, I would split the description with a function and would generate the inputs based on that.

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks i will try that... err sprint planning @ eesdil i am spliting the description with a regex but generating inputs that way means nesting the loop which prefer to avoid

Comment: Thanks for your help. 1st I had to fix my code since parameters are contained in the object so a nested loop should be the logical way to go about it.

Comment: As a side note i nested the description repeat inside the parameter repeat that way i bind the corresponding parameter when desc.includes('~')